# In Outlook 2007 Rules and Alerts, EXACTLY what does "my name" mean?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, email-filter

I can't find any definition of "my name" in the Outlook 2007 Rules and Alerts or on the Internet.

In this case our email system presents two email addresses for me to the outside world.  I'd like BOTH of these addresses to be recognized as being "me".

I thought that perhaps if I understood the definition of "my name" in the rules, I could set up my mailbox(es) appropriately.

Of course if "my name" actually means a single email address, then I won't be able to do so, but if it means "any email on my account" or "any account meeting [some criteria]", then I might be successful.

I'd like to note a subtlety in the rules definitions.  While there is a rule named "where my name is in the To or Cc box", the only rule for explicit addresses is "sent to people or distribution list" (I'm assuming that "sent to" means "in the To:" list rather than "in the To: or cc: lists").

Summing up.  My preference:
1) Understanding the precise definition of "my name" so that I can use "where my name is in the To or Cc box" to capture both email addresses from my account.
2) Learning the "sent to people or distribution list" actually includes Cc: entries (I can test this myself of course)
3) Any other solution that will let me define a rule where my secondary email address will be detected in EITHER the To: or Cc: boxes.

Answer (score 2):

1) "My name" includes all of your accounts. If you also check the **through the specified account** option then you can separate conditions by account.

2) **Sent to people or distribution list** includes the CC entries also
(Additionally you can use the **with specific words in the recipient's address**)

3) I think the best conditions are **through the specified account** and **with specific words in the recipient's address** - here you can add the exact email address)